# iOS Compare Arrays and Sets

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsset

I'm trying to compare two arrays to see if they match- My test cases are the "Winners" and I have been trying to compare them to halArray and playerArray with no luck. Even if I know that for example playerArray and win1 both have the same objects in them they don't seem to match up and trigger my NSLOG()

This is how the winners array is setup

```
NSArray  *win = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",nil];
winners = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: win1,win2,win3,win4,win5,win6,win7,win8,nil];
```

How comp and player are populated

```
-(void)checkSpace:(NSString *)playerName spot:(int)selectedSpot
{
    NSString *p = playerName;
    int s = selectedSpot;
    NSNumber* gameSpace = [NSNumber numberWithInt:s];

    if (p == comp)
    {    
        [halArray addObject:gameSpace];        
        [self checkWin];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to test if playerSet was a subset of testSet (and same for halSet) instead of the reverse case?
Please, attach a log of both sets and I am sure we will see what is happening.
Good luck!

Comment: Can you post how you are populating "playerArray" or "halArray"? and maybe example contents of each?

Comment: Ok updated - I add NSNumbers to the array. What I'm trying to do is add the space each user selects to the array and then compare the array to the possible "Wins" to know if they have won or not. So for example if the player selected spaces 0, 1 and 2 (they could have more but I only need to match the "Win) it would match "win1" and the game would be over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are populating the win array's with `NSString`'s and comparing them to the `NSNumber`'s that you populate `halArray` with.

**They will never match.**

Change this (and the other win's) from this:

```
NSArray  *win1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",nil];
```

to this:

```
NSArray  *win1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                                           nil];
```

**OR**

Add `NSString`'s instead of `NSNumbers` to `halArray` and `playerArray`.